# How can you fetch the id of a process in java?

Tags: java

How do I fetch the id of a process spawned by `Runtime.getRuntime().exec`?

Answer (score 1):

This is going to be environment/OS specific.

If you're on Unix, you can write a script to output the process id, and then `exec` to execute your required process. That process will replace the script in the process table and run with the same process id. e.g.

```
#!/bin/sh
echo $$
exec 'your program here'
```

So your parent Java process can spawn this, read the output, and the first line is your process id.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit** - As Brian pointed this get's the id of the running process and not of the spawned one.

First solution that i can think of, would be something like:

```
ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean().getName();
```

And you'll get something like: *18306@localhost*. 18306 is the process id.

Comment: That's the process id of the running process, not the spawned process. Note also that I don't believe that the above is completely reliable across JVM implementations (I use it, but it's a caveat worth being aware of)

Answer (score 0):

There's an API which allows you to query the process list from java: [Sigar](http://www.hyperic.com/products/sigar).  It looks commercial but it's actually GPL.  If you have some details about your spawned process you might be able to whip up a Sigar query which will return you the pid.

This is cross-platform.